# How to group and style tds in a table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to "group" a set of cells/`<td>` elements within a row/`<tr>` in a `<table>` so that I can apply styles to them. The below code achieves what I somewhat want to do, but it has some limitations:

```css
/* Styles I'm having issues with */
.row td:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: lightgray;
  /* potentially a box-shadow */
}

.row td:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.row td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}


/* Base styles for table to make it look decent */
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 1em; 
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above achives the visual effect I want (minus a box-shadow surrounding the grey box for each group), where the last 3 cells of each row are grouped. But it has a few issues:

1. This solution of stylying the last three cells involves me having to change the style of each `<td>`, which means that styling is tedious (eg: I have to style the border radius for each corner, and can't specify just one simple `border-radius` style for the group).
2. Stylying the table in this way makes it hard to do things like add cell-spacing between each cell (as it adds a white gap), or to add a box-shadow that surrounds the entire grey box that groups the last three cells (with the above approach, each box-shadow would need to be applied to each `<td>`, which makes each cell appear as seperate, [eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZbuW.png), whereas the desired look for the box-shadow for the group would be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCQ1e.png)).

Is there a way that I can group `<td>`s together so that I can apply my styles hollistically to the group, and not to the individual `<td>`s? Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```html
<tr class="row">
  <td>1</td>
  <div class="row-group">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </div>
</tr>
```

And then I would apply my `border-radius: 10px` and `background-color: lightgray` and `box-shadow` stylying to the `.row-group` class. But the HTML spec doesn't allow `<div>`s within `<tr>`s and so the above doesn't work. I have also tried looking into `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags, but these seem to apply styles per-column, and don't help me much with applying styles to a group of cells per-row. My only other thought is to use a sub-table, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way that will allow my to "group" and styles these `<td>`s collectively, maybe I'm missing something and it can be done with `<col>`s?

Comment: wouldn't something like `td:not(:first-child)` work for you?

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez that is what I've done in the code snippet at the start, but that has limitations (such as the box-shadow style I mentioned)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the code well. my bad. What about this? : https://jsfiddle.net/6cwqkomt/ It may work IF you know the width of your first child but if dynamic it would be easy with a few lines of javascript to calculate the width and add it as left property.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Oh yes, that looks promising! Thank you. I can make my first cell a fix width (and yes, using JS wouldn't be too difficult either if it was dynamic). If you would like to, you can post that as an answer and I'll +1 it, and if after some time nothing else comes along that I think is a better solution I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer as You told me.

Basically we use the `:after` pseudoelement with the styles You are looking for (rounded grey box) and position it as `absolute` under your `TD's`. It will take all row width except the `first:child` width.

```css
/* Styles I'm having issues with */
tbody tr {position:relative;}
tbody tr:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:30px; /*First child width*/
  margin:auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius:10px;
}
td {position:relative; z-index:1}
/* Base styles for table to make it look decent */
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 1em; 
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edited**: same snippet but adding a `jquery` script in case your `first-child` has a dynamic width:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tdWidth = $("td:first-child").outerWidth();
  $( "<style>tbody tr:after { left: " + tdWidth + "px; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )
});
```

```css
/* Styles I'm having issues with */
tbody tr {position:relative;}
tbody tr:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius:10px;
}
td {position:relative; z-index:1}
/* Base styles for table to make it look decent */
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 1em; 
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1111111</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```